# PHP coding conventions?

Tags: php

Where can I find PHP coding convention references for PHP coding standards?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suggest Zends Coding Standard: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.html

Comment: This link is currently broken as of April 27th, 2016

Comment: The link works as of December 13th, 2016 :)

Answer (score 15):

The [PEAR coding standards](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php) have been around for a while now.  I believe they are the default for the [PHP code sniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer).

Comment: Interesting. I'm not into PEAR, though.  I am not a fan of large frameworks unless I really need them (which I haven't until now.)

Comment: @Moshe: what have you been developing?

Comment: Zend is a large framework. PEAR is a just a candy store with cool stuff from the community in it.

Comment: @Misery - Very small stuff. Image uploaders with a database backend. I've toyed with logins. I am playing with the idea of building a CMS.
Petty things like I said.

Answer (score 11):

PSR-2: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md

(Excerpt)

This guide extends and expands on PSR-1, the basic coding standard.

The intent of this guide is to reduce cognitive friction when scanning code from different authors. It does so by enumerating a shared set of rules and expectations about how to format PHP code.

Answer (score 8):

The ones from [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.html) are very good.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is no official coding standard. I think the ones from [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.html) are used very often, because they are the company who develop php. But [symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/) for example, which is a large php mvc framework, has it's [own](http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/HowToContributeToSymfony#CodingStandards) conding standards.

Answer (score 3):

I would also like to mention that another popular framework, CakePHP, has their own conventions.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/22/CakePHP-Conventions

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at the [FLOW3 Coding Guidelines](http://docs.typo3.org/flow/TYPO3FlowDocumentation/TheDefinitiveGuide/PartV/CodingGuideLines/Index.html). It is very good.