# Coding convention

Tags: php, naming-conventions, conventions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP coding conventions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863790/php-coding-conventions)

Are there any coding conventions regarding PHP? I'm looking for naming convention in particular such as:

> For function use `nameOfFunction()` rather than `name_of_function()`

or

> For variables don't use `$first_array = array()` but `$array['first'] = array()`

or

> Classes should always start with a capital letter: `class Name`

Are there any? Shouldn't they be defined so that different programmers will now how the entire code is written?

Comment: Why should they be defined? Don't you think it's up to you, or me to decide what's easier to write or read? There's no set rule what's right or wrong, and there shouldn't be. On the other hand, if you are looking for a language with such restrictions (or features), you might be interested in Python.

Comment: its generally up to a project to define its own conventions, or in the case of using a framework, often those conventions are followed, or in some cases, required

Comment: @N.B. So that when you'll read my code and I'll your we will find it easier to get used to it.

Comment: What Will said - if it's a team effort, then team agrees on the standard that's going to be used. There isn't defacto standard that says "this methodology is better than that methodology" since defining what's easier to read for you is entirely subjective and cannot be defined in global.

Comment: @N.B. Creating like 2 or 3 standards could be useful. Coders would learn them all and at the beginning of the code they'll comment: `// I'm using A standard`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are the [PEAR Standards](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php)

Answer (score 4):

1. `nameOfFunction` vs `name_of_function` - this one is entirely up to you. PHP itself doesn't even stick to a consistent scheme in this regard.
2. Those two things are different, and can't really be compared, especially in the context of coding conventions.
3. AFAIK, it's fairly common across quite a few programming languages that classes start with a capital letter (and hence, variables and functions don't).

*Edit*: Sorry, I just re-read the question and saw that you were looking for a more general document. The [Zend Coding Standards](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.html) are pretty good for that.

Answer (score 2):

Some standard like Zend Framework's : http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.html

Php_CodeSniffer allows to verify if your code is compatible with some standards and also custom standards.

http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/redirected

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no such thing as a document like Python PEPs for PHP code conventions.

Here you have some links from Google searches that try to address this:

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/shindig/trunk/php/docs/style-guide.html
http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/tim20010101.php3?page=2

There's this Style Guide frm CodeIgniter web framwrok project, it could work as a guideline in creating some personal or corporate conventions.

Hope this helps, regards.

Comment: Forgot link for CodeIgniter reference
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html