# PHP Coding style - Best practices

Tags: php, coding-style

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Coding convention to follow for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139427/which-coding-convention-to-follow-for-php)

After coding for a while similar in terms to the coding style offered by zend, im constantly finding myself getting told to change my code at work.  They prefer a different coding style.  For example a huge annoyance for them is using:

```
funtction testFunction
{

}
```

instead of

```
function testFunction {
```

}

To me the first option is much more readable.  The same for class declerations.

Anyway there are more little things like this and overall i feel that the code i write at work is much less readable than other code i write using my own style.

Are there any industry wide best practices for code standards?