# Accessing class instance from different file [PHP]

Tags: php

I have a php class (server class) responsible for communication between arduino and server. Class has a looping method listening to a server socket, and calling method for handling incoming messages and sending the response to arduino. It also has an information of all connected devices and their addresses.

Now I would like to make API in php that would communicate with mobile app and call server class method that would forward the message to the arduino. API part is not the problem, but the way how to trigger and send info from API to class with a looping method.

Is there a way to access class instance from Server class inside API file so I could call it's methods and use info about connected devices?

EDIT

Here is a simplyfied code example. Main file that is creating class instance:

```
<?php
require_once("SocketServer.class.php");
$server = new SocketServer("X.Y.Z.Y",PORT);
$server->max_clients = 10; 

$server->hook("CONNECT","handle_connect"); 
$server->hook("INPUT","handle_input"); 
$server->infinite_loop(); 
....
```

and the file from which I would like to access instance *$server* instantiated in the previous file

```
<?php
    include ("phpscript.php");
    $server->test();
?>
```

Then, I start the first script and when HTTP request is sent to the second one (.htaccess is forwarding reqests to this file) using hurl.it I get the server error message, which means that there is a error in the code.

I'm expecting that looping script outputs echo from the test method of *SocketServer* class, but that doesn't happen.

Comment: Try to read marked answer of the link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426336/calling-php-classes-from-other-files

Comment: I've added some code so the question makes more sense.

Comment: I've read the marked answer but that does not help since I would like to use already created instance of the class, because it contains information about connected clients.