# PHP How To Know When To Put A Space Between A Word And Parentheses

Tags: php, naming-conventions

I have been recommended to put a space between foreach and (, among other things.  My understanding is that it helps to differentiate between functions and everything else.

I was just working with an array and noticed that you are supposed to `unset($value)`.  I looked up `unset` and it's a construct.  `foreach` is also a construct.  Then I looked and `array` is also a construct.  No one seems to put a space with `unset` or `array`, though.

How do you know when to put a space in and not?  I use Adobe Dreamweaver, so I just got into a habit of putting a space after every php word that was colored green (like `include_once`).

JJ

Edit...

It's possible that it has something to do with keywords http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php.  I noticed that `foreach` is a keyword, but `array()` is also a keyword.

JJ

Comment: Just pick a style and stick with it.

Comment: This is completely personal preference.

Comment: Coding conventions may often seem arbitrary. Note that `foreach` is a keyword and `unset` is a library function. There are few questions on SO such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350560/php-coding-style-best-practices) which may be of help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's many different coding conventions for php. The Zend standards seem to be very close to most code I see:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.html

Anyway, probably a space after [control structure](http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php) keywords

Answer (score 0):

Do you as a more comfortable, but the only way. and yet [php coding standart](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV/PHP+Coding+Standard+%28draft%29#PHPCodingStandard%28draft%29-Scope)