# Good coding practice with PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html

Out of curiosity, I just want to ask about a good coding practice. The below code have the same outputs but have difference coding practice.

So, which is better?

This one:

```
<?php foreach ($cart as $item): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $item['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $item['checkin']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $item['checkout']; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Or this one:

```
<?php 
    foreach ($cart as $item):
      echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$item['name']</td>";
        echo "<td>$item['checkin']</td>";
        echo "<td>$item['checkout']</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    endforeach; 
?>
```

Comment: Using templates is the best practice

Comment: Both are correct and good but I prefer the first one

Comment: Neither will have any effect on performance. Again, I prefer the first one myself. Always best to separate code when possible, just for readability sake.

Comment: Escaping output is also best practice :)

Comment: First one! But is anyone else thinking this might be able to be simplified more by removing the excessive <td>'s and just looping through the item keys out of being lazy in the second?

Comment: Better suits to ask at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would replace <?php echo $item['name']; ?> with <?=$item['name'];?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends where and what kind of script you are using.Above from those two samples I will choose the first one.Because if you will go through the code you can see proper indentation with spaces are maintained there.It helps to debug the code.If you are asking about HTML codes then first work is to check whether the code is valid or not.Because code validation makes ease to debug. Here are some of the links, just go through them.Hopefully you will get some to make your code more good

[PHP Coding style - Best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350560/php-coding-style-best-practices)

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/30-php-best-practices-for-beginners/

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-5goodhabits/index.html

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html

Answer (score 1):

Both ways of doing it are correct syntax in PHP.  Neither will have an advantage over the other - it all depends on what you prefer.  I think the first one looks cleaner and is a lot more legible, but it's really your choice.

Answer (score 1):

First one seems better... consider cases when you need to get some custom rows or columns to be added...

Also keeping the individual tags also allows you for customizations as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would say first one is better, as when debugging code or viewing source of page, it will maintain tabbing/spaces. It also keeps your page structure separate from your server-side code, so a bit cleaner in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

PHP language has it's origins as a templating language. It still has this aspect and you should learn to use it.

You might find [**this article**](http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html) quite useful (thought I disagree with use of magic methods). It will explain a simple methods how to separate the business logic from your HTML fragments.