# Why is a newline converted into a ' ' in any given .html file?

Tags: html, newline

I have a question related to HTML. In order to demonstrate my
simple question, I will use a minimal example.

Consider the following HTML content:

```
<html>
Foo: Bar 
</html>
```

When you call this in a browser, it displays "Foo: Bar" in
one line. So far so good.

However had, when you do almost the same, and store this:

```
<html>
Foo
: Bar 
</html>
```

In other words, if you add a newline right before the ':'
character, then suddenly the display becomes this here:

```
"Foo : Bar"
```

Now I wonder where from the ' ' comes? Because that character
is not part of the original source.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the browser renders a newline as space?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588356/why-does-the-browser-renders-a-newline-as-space) and [How do line breaks in your HTML affect your resulting page's spacing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14886354/139010). The short version (as always): because [that's what the spec says.](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/white-space#Values)

Answer (score 1):

In HTML a carriage return or line feed in the source code is treated as white space and rendered as a space. Multiple spaces or white space (CR, LF, tabs, etc.) amount to a single white space on the rendered page.

So if you have 50 carriage returns in your source code between `Foo` and `: Bar` it will render a one space (`Foo : Bar`) when th HTML page is displayed in the browser.

From the HTML 4.01 spec: [**Controlling line breaks**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#line-breaks).