# if / elseif syntax

Tags: php

I'm having some trouble with the following code, more than likely a n00b error so apologies in advance if the answer is obvious. The if/elseif/if works without the content but not with the test statements. Is there some subtlety of syntax i'm missing.

```
<?php 

if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/workshops/') !== false) {echo ''

}; elseif ($ticketlink = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Ticket-Link-1', true))

{ echo '<div class="artist-buy-tickets-box"><a class="artist-buy-button" href="'.$ticketlink.'" title="Buy tickets" target="_blank">Buy Tickets</a>';}

else { echo '<h6>TICKETS ON SALE<br/>JUNE 15 2011</h6>' ;}

?>
```

Comment: I'm not going to suggest a specific flavor (and start a flamewar), but IMHO any reasonable indenting scheme would make this error much more likely to stand out.

Comment: I haven't really done much in the way of php development I mostly so any feedback is useful! Are there any recommended/most common indenting schemes for php

Comment: I'd say any flavour of code style/indenting would be a step up from that :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139427/which-coding-convention-to-follow-for-php

Comment: Fair comment looking at other people's examples!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `;` after your `if` and missing a `;` after the first echo

```
<?php 
if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/workshops/') !== false) {
    echo '';
}
elseif ($ticketlink = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Ticket-Link-1', true)) {
    echo '<div class="artist-buy-tickets-box"><a class="artist-buy-button" href="'.$ticketlink.'" title="Buy tickets" target="_blank">Buy Tickets</a>';
}
else { 
    echo '<h6>TICKETS ON SALE<br/>JUNE 15 2011</h6>';
}
?>
```

Comment: When constructing if/elseif if statements are there any tricks for efficiency?

Comment: @toomanyairmiles If you mean performance by efficiency no i don't think there's much to gain there. However efficiency in having your code easier to read then there's a few styles, all 3 being represented by myself, midas and Anton's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You just have a small syntax mistake. And how is this code formatting readable for you? Use something like this instead:

```
<?php 
if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/workshops/') !== false) {
    echo '';
} elseif ($ticketlink = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Ticket-Link-1', true)) {
    echo '<div class="artist-buy-tickets-box"><a class="artist-buy-button" href="' . $ticketlink . '" title="Buy tickets" target="_blank">Buy Tickets</a>';
} else {
    echo '<h6>TICKETS ON SALE<br/>JUNE 15 2011</h6>';
}
?>
```

The error is this: `echo '' };`, should be `echo ''; }`.

Answer (score 1):

Lose the semi-colon before "elseif";

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
if(stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/workshops/') !== false) 
{
   echo '';
} 
elseif ($ticketlink = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Ticket-Link-1', true)) 
{ 
   echo '<div class="artist-buy-tickets-box"><a class="artist-buy-button" href="'.$ticketlink.'" title="Buy tickets" target="_blank">Buy Tickets</a>';
} 
else 
{ 
   echo '<h6>TICKETS ON SALE<br/>JUNE 15 2011</h6>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is really messy. Try cleaning it up a little bit and most syntax errors will reveal themselves right away.

Here is your code with better formatting and dropped semicolon that was causing your problems:

```
<?php 

if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/workshops/') !== false)
{
    echo ''
} elseif ($ticketlink = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Ticket-Link-1', true)) {
    echo '<div class="artist-buy-tickets-box"><a class="artist-buy-button" href="'.$ticketlink.'" title="Buy tickets" target="_blank">Buy Tickets</a>';
} else {
    echo '<h6>TICKETS ON SALE<br/>JUNE 15 2011</h6>';
}

?>
```