# About php addition

Tags: php, addition

Just want to know that should i put space between the number and addition sign like this 4 + 5 or just go without putting space like this 4+5. I mean is there any difference between them.

Answer (score 5):

There are no differences in terms of the result. However, coding standards (or simply personal preference if you are working alone) may dictate that you use one form in preference to another.

Comment: Funnily enough, there is/was: [php hexadecimal addition bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61095).

Comment: @Femaref that is unbelievable :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how readable you want your code to be.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3350564/427992) a brief overview of what you should be trying to do when writing good, well-formatted code.